# Hiding methods from other classes when inheriting from a class and Interface or Abstract class

Tags: c#, interface, logic, abstract-class, object-oriented-analysis

To improve further implementation and to offer some guidelines and keep everything as universal as possible within the project I've created an Interface with a few methods which should be used. However only one method of this class should be visible to the user calling that class so I'd like them to be of the protected variety. E.g

```
public class ClassThree
{
    public ClassThree()
    {
        var classOne = new ClassOne();
        class1.MethodOne();
    }
}
```

This despite ClassOne having 4 methods, 3 methods are used only within the one public class, hence private or protected. These 3 methods are required to make the 4th method work however (in an ideal world other developers would follow the same principle). So I don't want to see the following pop up on intellisense:

```
class1.MethodTwo();
class1.MethodThree();
class1.MethodFour();
```

I know one can implicitly call methods from an Interface e.g

```
IInterface.MethodTwo<Type,Type>(string name)
{
  //Do stuff here
}
```

However I would like to prevent all the casting when calling said methods in ClassOne itself since this is just a thorn in my eye. I like my code clean and this isn't clean at all to me. I've thought of an abstract class however my class is inheriting from another class. With the interface I could just do

```
public ClassOne : ClassTwo, IInterface<Type1,Type2>
```

When I do that with an Abstract class however Visual Studio says an interface is expected. Any insights are most welcome and appreciated as I would like to up my code by making my life and that of fellow developers, who have to use my code, easier.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The scenario is there can be several classes like ClassOne which essentially do the same however they use different types since the objects they have to return hold different values. However the buildup to these objects are more or less the same e.g:

1. Collect all API data
2. Retrieve the list to be exported to the API and call #3 or #4 depending on the type.
3. Export Type 1 to the API
4. Export Type 2 to the API

The idea is always the same but naturally different API's will require different variables. But to ensure all steps are followed as before I'd like to implement an Interface or something but step 1,2 and 3 should be private or protected and only step 2 should be available to the class that consumed it. However if I only put method 2 in the interface I can never be sure that others will implement 1,3 & 4. And that's kind of the goal here :P. This while ClassOne also inherits from another class and not just the interface.

Edit 2: I know Interfaces only provide public methods which is why I'm looking for alternatives hence this question. I know what is wrong with it I just don't really see how I can get it the way I would like it to be. Thanks for the replies so far!

Edit 3: Interface currently looks like this, I just adjusted variable names for sake of example.

```
   public interface IExport<in T, in TU>
    {
        void GetRequiredApiData();

        bool MethodOne(List<Type> list);

        bool ExportOne(T one);

        bool ExportTwo(TU two);

        bool ValidateExport();
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you're saying. You being talking about an interface in the first paragraph, but that somehow turns into a class mid sentence. This class (`ClassOne` I presume) has some methods you want to hide from consuming code. Could you please elaborate on why making the members private or protected doesn't work? Also, what is `ClassThree`? Is that the consuming code?

Comment: Added extra explanation, hope it's more clear now!

Comment: All the methods from an Interface are public, and by design, you can inherit your data only from 1 class (even if it is abstract).
Hope this helps  you

Comment: @darkndream Is there any possible alternative I can use? All logic is pretty much there It's just these 3 methods when invoking the class that pokes my eye out Other than creating a text file which says try following this guideline (which more than likely will never work) :P.

Comment: Instead of searching for alternatives, I'd say you probably should follow what you're running into. Try having nothing exposed but one public method to kick this process off. Everything else should be internal to this class. If it requires taking that calling code from outside and putting it in this class, so be it. It shouldn't be problematic and will probably help decouple things anyway.

Comment: Added the interface example.. this is not so much for making the code function more so that these 5 methods will be implemented by every developer working on future parts of this part of the project. So it's easier to understand in the long run. Sorry if I'm being an idiot here haha. I don't have to use an interface or an abstract class since it can be done fine without. I just want a universal guideline within this part of the project to follow.

Comment: I would avoid that kind of design up front because it can be really difficult to refactor 85 objects that consist primarily of copy-pasted boilerplate. To accomplish what you want, though, instead of using this object to do all the work, keep the one public method on this object, and have it call the 4 methods on another object you create, which utilizes an abstract class to define protected methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other three methods should just be called inside your public method, or make your first method private/protected and call all 4 inside one public method.

The whole point of an interface is to hide exactly what is problematic for you--the other three methods that the caller doesn't need to know about.

I suspect you need to have those three methods called at separate, specific times, in a specific order. If that's the case then you have a code smell. Those methods are probably just void subroutines that have side effects and change global state. The code needs to be refactored to not be just a series of subroutines and objects need to be broken out differently.

Comment: In my class I have a few properties which are lists of objects. These are filled in the first method by class methods in the Get class (which is inherited). This Get class calls the static Request class which holds generic methods to make API calls while providing the required types etc. Then I can use those values to see if they are actually available in the API I'm targeting otherwise bad requests will happen. Once these validations pass I can export said object to the API. Is there any way I can improve this logic?

Comment: Put the type parameters you need on the method(s), not the object itself. That way you can keep your inheritance structure without the type parameters meddling.